ngnix php8.0-fpm Primary script unknown
I have a nginx server and add a laravel project in /var/www/main-site and address site.com
i added a wordpress project to /var/www/blog. i want to show blog with this address site.com/blog.
this my nginx config
    listen 80;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    root /var/www/main-site/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    charset utf-8;

    location /blog {
            alias /var/www/blog;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
            }
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}

when i call site.com, it works and shows laravel project. but when i call site.com/blog, I see File not found with 404 status. and in nginx log shows this error
2024/04/30 22:12:16 [error] 3577550#3577550: *7 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xx.xx, server: site.com, request: "GET /blog/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock:", host: "site.com"

Try:
location ^~ /blog {
    root /var/www;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$query_string;

    ...
}

The location statement needs the ^~ operator, otherwise /blog/index.php will be processed by the wrong location ~ \.php$ block.
You should use root instead of alias - where you can.
The final parameter of the try_files statement is the action taken when the file is not found. Did you mean to divert to your other application at /index.php, or stay with /blog/index.php?
